# arabxetex: madda vocalization

Tags: arabic, right-to-left, arabxetex

I need to produce a madda sign without any preceding fatha, just the madda. I can't understand why the MWE below stubbornly produces a vowel above the mim, as in the following image.

[image: madda-fatha problem]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}

\begin{arab}
al-asm^A 
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

I've tried playing around with the quotation mark and whatnot, to no avail. I wonder if someone could try? Dirty fixes are welcome too.
Thanks, J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation of `ArabTeX`’s input convention in the `ArabTeX` documentation suggests, none too clearly, that `^A` is useful for reproducing some historic spellings, and that `'A` is more generally useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Language=Arabic,Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
al-asm^A

al-asm'A
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

Even when using `arabxetex`, the documentation for `ArabTeX` is often essential; the former seems to assume it and not to repeat everything useful.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! What an ungrateful wretch I was not to go back straight to good old ArabTeX manual!